# Bundling & Minification in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Can you use the new ASP.NET 4.5 bundling and minification features in Orchard CMS?

In my layout.cshtml, "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")" is not recognised.

If so what do I need to do to enable it?

Thanks

Comment: Note to former me - use Composite C1 instead of the massively over complicated Orchard - WAY simpler better CMS, and largely free. I have now used it on many projects.